# How to show that $f^{\star}\in\mathcal{H}(G^{\star})$ where $f^{\star}(z)=\overline{f(\frac{1}{\overline z}) }$?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, solution-verification, power-series, analytic-continuation

$G\subset \Bbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ be a domain (open and connected). Let $G^{\star}$ be the reflection of $G$ w.r.to the unit circle $S^1$. Given $f\in\mathcal{H}(G) $ ,then show that $f^{\star}\in\mathcal{H}(G^{\star})$ where $f^{\star}(z)=\overline{f(\frac{1}{\overline z}) }$.

My attempt:

A mobius map $T\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$ maps a straight line or circle into straight line or circle and being conformal it preserves angle between any two points. Hence $z^{\star}$ is the reflection of the point $z$ about $S$ (straight line or circle) then $T(z^{\star}) $ is the reflection of $T(z) $ about $T(S) $.

Consider the mobius map $T(z) =\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

Then $T$ maps Real line onto the unit circle.
Since $\overline{z}$ is the reflection of $z$ w.r.to Real axis, $w^{\star}=T(\overline{z}) $ will be the reflection of $w=T(z) $ w.r.to the unit circle.

$w^{\star}=T(\overline{z}) =\frac{\overline{z}-i}{\overline{z}+i}=\frac{1}{\overline{\frac{z-i}{z+i}}}=\frac{1}{\overline{w}}$

$G^{\star}=\{\frac{1}{\overline{w}}:w\in G\}$

This proves that $f^{\star}$ is well defined on $G^{\star}$.

To show $f^{\star}\in\mathcal{H}(G^{\star}) $ , let $z_0\in G^{\star}$ .

Then $\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}}\in G$ and $f\in \mathcal{H}(G) $ implies $f$ has a convergent power series $B_{\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}}}(R) $ for some $R>0$ . Let $f(z) =\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n (z-\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}})^n$

Then $f^{\star}(z) =\sum_{n\ge 0}\overline{a_n} (\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z_0})^n$

**I want to express $f^{\star}$ in the form :
$f^{\star}(z) =\sum_{n\ge 0}b_n(z-z_0)^n$**

How to use $B_{\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}}}(R) $ to get the above form?

Comment: The reflection in the unit circle is precisely the map $z\mapsto \frac{1}{\bar z}$. As it is anti-holomorphic, the composition with $f\in H(G)$ is also anti-holomorphic. In order to recover a holomorphic map, just compose with the conjugation

Comment: In what part exactly can't you fill the details? Also, what is your definition of holomorphic? Mine is "differentiable with complex-linear differential"

Comment: From $$f^{\star}(z) =\sum_{n\ge 0}\overline{a_n} (\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z_0})^n$$ to a power series of $f^{\star}$ at $z_0$

Comment: What I proposed was a shortcut that does not use any power series.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot right now. But I suggest you to think about my previous comments: in my opinion, computing the power series is inefficient and too complicated to answer the question

Comment: I don't want to bump the question needlessly, but if you have the chance to edit, could you please remove the `complex-geometry` tag? (The `geometry` tag is appropriate.)